ELK: How to apply results of field values of keyword1 to be keyword2
Is it possible? If I'd like to search log by "abcd" then the result of fieldname aID is "111","222",..
and then search log by using multiple string contain aID values and "xxxx"
In my logstash pipeline
if [message] =~ "abcd"  {
   grok { match => { "message" => "%{DATA:aID}" }  }    
}
if aID in [message] =~ "xxxx" [message] =~ "yyyy"{
   grok { match => { "message" => "%{DATA:dName}" }  } 
}   
        

